# Uniformly continuous functions on the interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous.

Prove $\exists$
$M > 0$ s.t $$\frac{\big|f(x)\big|}{x} \leq M, \hspace{11pt} \forall x\in[1,\infty)$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? My suggestion: try $\varepsilon=1$ in the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: I having issues with the interval not  closed.

Comment: A followup hint: by applying the definition repeatedly, you get that $|f(x)-f(1)|<n$ if $|x-1|<n\delta$.

Comment: yes it is similar however not exactly the same

Comment: @juheelee It is very easy to prove your result from that one. (By comparison, I wouldn't say that either result is very easy to prove directly.)